# Extract values from array type of column in pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, text

I am trying to extract the location codes / product codes from a sql table using pandas. The field is an array type, i.e. it has multiple values as a list within each row. I have to extract values from string for product/location codes.

**Here is a sample of the table**

```
df.head()
Target_Type Constraints
45          ti_8188,to_8188,r_8188,trad_8188_1,to_9258,ti_9258,r_9258,trad_9258_1   
45          ti_8188,to_8188,r_8188,trad_8188_1,trad_22420_1   
45          ti_8894,trad_8894_0.2
```

Now I want to extract the numeric values of the codes. I also want to ignore the end float values after 2nd underscore in the entries, i.e. ignore the _1, _0.2 etc.

Here is a sample output I want to achieve. It should be unique list/df column of all the extracted values -

```
 Target_Type_45_df.head()
 Constraints
 8188
 9258
 22420
 8894
```

I have never worked with nested/array type of column before. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use explode to bring each variable into a single cell, under one column:

```
df = df.explode('Constraints')
df['newConst'] = df['Constraints'].apply(lambda x: str(x).split('_')[1])
```

Comment: thanks @yashar and @adrian. I was able to solve it. Although, _direct_ explode didn't work, I used the following to help me with the issue - 

`df = df.assign(constraints=df['constraints'].str.split(',')).explode('constraints')`

`df['constraints'] = df['constraints'].apply(lambda x: str(x).split('_')[1])`

Comment: yw :) I am just curious why the explode didn't work. I replicated the sample data and it worked just fine. Can you tell me if you got an error or unusable result?

Comment: it didn't throw any error. It simply didn't do anything. my dataframe was same after running the script.

Answer (score 1):

I would think the following overall strategy would work well (you'll need to debug):

1. Define a function that takes a `row` as input (the idea being to broadcast this function with the pandas `.apply` method).
2. In this function, set `my_list = row['Constraints']`.
3. Then do `my_list = my_list.split(',')`. Now you have a list, with no commas.
4. Next, split with the underscore, take the second element (index 1), and convert to int:

```
numbers = [int(element.split('_')[1]) for element in my_list]
```

5. Finally, convert to `set`: `return set(numbers)`

The output for each row will be a set - just union all these sets together to get the final result.